# Google maps polygons

Tags: javascript, maps, polygon

I want to draw multiple polygons in the same google map, what i need to do is to read latlngs from a listbox, they are in this way:

lat1,lng1,1
lat2,lng2,1
lat3,lng3,1
lat1,lng1,2
lat2,lng2,2
lat3,lng3,2

and depending on the value at the right(1 or 2) I will read the corresponding latlns and draw the polygon, actually i'm doing this, in my loop the polygons are painted but there´s a line connecting them, what can I do?,I mean, HOW CAN I DRAW POLYGONS WITHOUT THIS CONNECTING LINES?, thank you very much!!!

Here's my code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var bermudaTriangle=[];
        var places = [];
        var geoDataSplit;
        function initialize() {

            var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
            var coords = document.getElementById("selPoly");

            var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(19.3162200000000, -99.2204930000000),
                zoom: 12,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });

            var latlng;

            for (var i = 0; i < coords.options.length; i++) 
                {
                    var geoData = coords.options[i].text;
                    geoDataSplit = geoData.split(",");
                    var counter = geoDataSplit[2];

                    for (geoDataSplit[2] = 1; geoDataSplit[2] <= 2; geoDataSplit[2]++)

                    {


                        if (counter == geoDataSplit[2]) {

                            latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(geoDataSplit[0]), parseFloat(geoDataSplit[1]));
                            places.push(latlng);

                            bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
                                paths: places,
                                strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                                strokeWeight: 2,
                                fillColor: "#FF0000",
                                fillOpacity: 0.35
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
                bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
    </head>


  <body style="font-family: Arial; border: 0 none;">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ListBox ID="selPoly" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
    </div>
    </form>

    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 1024px; height: 768px"></div>
  </body>
```

Comment: What are the exact values returned by `var coords = document.getElementById("selPoly")`

Comment: are combinatins of lat/lngs and Id, for example 19.4646565,-99.43435353,1 so i make the split to get each value

Answer (score 0):

Drawing polygons is drawing lines between points (the subsequent points you give, and possibly the first and last point on your list). When they enclose a space - you get a polygon and the space is filled with colour. The line is always there between the two subsequent points.

If you want separate polygons, you have to CREATE separate polygons (with `new google.maps.Polygon`). If all you get is a list of points, it is up to you to come up with or find an algorithm to detect that the space is already enclosed, and a new Polygon should be created.

By the way, with the algoritm as is now, the `new google.maps.Polygon` line could (and probably should) be pushed down, outside of the loop, in line preceding  `bermudaTriangle.setMap(map)`;

OH WAIT THERE ACTUALLY IS A SOLUTION. Or a half-solution at least. You can make the lines invisible (`strokeOpacity: 0`). The polygons will still be visible because of their filling, more or less like this:
[image]